# Conflicting outputs when value referenced by a pointer no longer exists

Tags: c++, function, pointers

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
int *p;
void Set()
{
   int i;
   i=7;
   p=&i;
}
int Use()  
{
   double d;
   d=3.0;
   d+=*p;
//if i replace the above 3 statements with --> double d=3.0+*p; then output is 10          otherwise the output is some random value(address of random memory location)
//why is this happening? Isn't it the same? 
   return d;
}
void main()
{
   clrscr();
   Set();
   cout<<Use();
   getch();
}
```

My question is as mentioned in comments above.I want to know the exact reason for the difference in outputs.In the above code output is some address of random memory location and i understand that is because of i is a local variable of Set() but then how is it visible in the second case that is by replacing it with double d=3.0+*p; because then the output comes 10( 7+3 ) although 7 should not have been visible?

Comment: Do you happen to have a `TAB` on your keyboard?

Comment: Also, there's no reasonable explanation to the unreasonable. UB is UB.

Comment: I think this question is more about what happens in the compiler/on assembly level than about correct C usage. The poster mentioned that he understands, that the code is invalid in the sense that it provokes undefined behaviour. He just wanted an explanation of why some particular behaviour occurs. It's not a bad question, since it helps understanding, what "undefined behaviour" means (in concrete, technical implementations) and why it can lead to errors, which are hard to detect (because they may not occur in the first place).

Comment: @H2CO3 Theres always some explanation...

Comment: @MartinStettner And in this case, it's that "every behavior is correct", since you have UB.

Comment: @H2CO3 For every "forbidden" thing you can always just say "because it's forbidden" ... Or you can explain what happens exactly. I think this leads to a deeper understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of using pointer `p` is undefined, it could also give you a segfault or just return 42. The technical reason behind the results your'e getting are probably:

- `i` inside `Set` is placed on the stack. The value 7 ist stored there and `p` points to that location in memory. When you return from `Set` value remains in memory: the stack is not "destroyed", it's just the stack pointer which is reset. `p` still points to this location which still contains the integer representation of "3".
- Inside `Use` the same location on the stack is reused for `d`.
- When the compiler is not optimizing, in the first case (i.e. the whole computation in one line), it first uses the value 7 (which is still there in memory with `p` pointing to it), does the computation, overwrites the value (since you assign it to `d` which is at the same location) and returns it.
- In the second case, it *first* overwrites the value withe the double value 3.0 and then takes the first 4 bytes interpreted as integer value for evaluating `*p` in `d+=*p`.

This case shows why returning pointers/references to local variables is such a bad thing: when writing the function `Set` you could even write some kind of unit tests and they would not detect the error. It might get unnoticed just until the software goes into production and has to perform some really critical task and just fails then.

This applies to all kindes of "undefined behaviour", especially in "low level" languages like C/C++. The bad thing is that "undefined" may very well mean "perfectly working until it's too late"...

Answer (score 0):

After exiting function Set the value of pointer p becomes invalid due to destroying local variable i. The program has undefined behavior.

Comment: thats my point. If i is destroyed then why double d=3.0+*p; gives the output 10 ?